# How to round only non integer numbers to one decimal place in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using `MySQL` and I want to display the values (which are all decimals) from a `SELECT` query as follows: when the number has non zero decimals, then it should be rounded to one decimal place; when it is an integer, then to display with no decimal places.

Hence `3.26` should be displayed as `3.3` whereas `5.00` should be displayed as `5`.

When I use `ROUND(x,1)` to the above I get `3.3` and `5.0` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
select  
case (yournumber mod 1 > 0)  
  when true then round(yournumber, 1)   
  else round(yournumber,0) 
end 
from tablename;
```